# how can i make black and white alpha video effect

Tags: video-sequence-editor, compositing-nodes

I mean using a real footage (not 3d)just like the "Renaissance (2006)movie"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GM5KCoWNXF4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> - Adjustment Layer to add an  Adjustment strip, and place it above all video strips.
2. In <kbd>N</kbd>-panel find saturation value and change it down to `0`
3. In <kbd>N</kbd>-panel open modifiers tab and add curves modifier. Draw a curve in the modifier like this:

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: That was quick!!! You're awsome!! thanks for your  help

Comment: just one more  question... how can i save the video?